# When does a program developed in VC++ need .NET Framework installed on the target machine and when does it need the MS VC++ Redistributable Package?

Tags: .net, visual-c++

Background:  I program primarily in Java but every once in a while I call some functions contained within a .dll compiled in VC++. I'm trying to make an installer package that checks for prerequisites for my program.  I am trying to understand when the target computer needs to have .NET Framework to run my program and when it needs the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package.

I believe the following questions will help me understand the answer to my main question:

Say I write and successfully compile a program consisting of one simple 'cout << "hi";' statement in Visual C++. Does the machine on which the program is intended to run need to have .NET Framework installed?

What is the difference between the so-called Common Language Runtime and Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages(which I understand to be another type of runtime)?

Comment: What error do you get when you run on different machine? May be it is not asking about .NET framework.

Comment: No error, I'm sorry, maybe I shouldn't have put "I'm trying".  I'm more trying to figure out what are the prereqs for running an app developed in vc++.

Comment: You just need correct VC++ Redistributable package installted. It mean - correct VC version, correct service pack and correct machine (32-bit or 64-bit).

Answer (score 3):

You only need the .NET framework if you are using it. A simple `cout << "hi";` program would need absolutely no additional packages/frameworks to be successfully run on any DOS/Windows (assuming it's a console application) platform.

If, however, you are making use of any of the functionality of the .NET framework - then, expectedly, you need it to be present on the target machine.

As for the redistributable - here's an excerp from MSDN:

> This package installs runtime components of C Runtime (CRT), Standard C++, ATL, MFC, OpenMP and MSDIA libraries

Which means you'd need the libraries (DLLs) from this package if you use them as DLLs. You can still easily link most of the needed components into your executable directly, in which case you don't need the DLLs. Of you can specify that you'd rather use a shared DLL resource for the libraries' code in which case you need the Redistributable run-times on the target machine.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you provide me with more info or perhaps a link detailing how to go about linking the needed components directly into the executable?  I needed to install the redistributable runtime on the target machine because I needed the msvcr100.dll file.